# Perform wireTap using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to do wireTap using camel.

Below is the piece of code I have written

```
from("jetty:http://xyz:8080?enableMultipartFilter=false")
                    .streamCaching()
                    .wireTap("direct:tap").copy(true).process(new WireTapProcessor()).end()
.process(new RequestProcessor())
.to("file:Z:/Testing/input");
```

When executing above code, it gives me exception that NoDirectConsumersAvailable.

Could you please suggest how to perform wireTap in above scenario

Answer (score 0):

Well you send the Wire Tap to a direct consumer but you dont create a direct consumer route or in other words you never define the other route to handle the wire tap. I use seda queues here instead of direct queues.

Try the following:

```
from("jetty:http://xyz:8080?enableMultipartFilter=false")
                .streamCaching()
                .wireTap("seda:wiretapqueue")
 .process(new RequestProcessor())
 .to("file:Z:/Testing/input");

 from("seda:wiretapqueue").to("somecomponent:foo");
```

This should resolve your issue. Also see [this link](http://fusesource.com/docs/router/2.2/eip/_IDU_WireTap.html)

Comment: Using above it gives me exception as:

Comment: It gives exception: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route2 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: Endpoint[direct://tap]
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:2142)

Comment: We have added routebuilder and started camel as below: Main main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new XyzRouteBuilder());
        main.run(args);

Comment: Please try it with seda queues.

Comment: you should use .wireTap("direct:mytap") and then from("direct:mytap")

Comment: what is the difference between sending the wiretap to a direct or a seda endpoint? the wiretap exchange is already "InOnly" type so there is no response waiting or it becomes more effective because at the other end there are also multiple consumers waiting for the wiretap?