# Camel Rest DSL - multicast and early reply to http client

Tags: rest, apache-camel

Camel version is 2.18.1

I have the following routes:

1: A rest dsl accepting data from HTTP clients and sending it to the route
below before replying to the client.

```
rest("/api")
    .post("/commands/{command}").to("direct:commands")
```

2: A multicast to route the command to two endpoints `longRunningProces` and `shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpClient`.

```
from("direct:commands")
    .multicast()
        .to("direct:longRunningProces")
        .to("direct:shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpClient");
```

How can I send to Http Client the response from the shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpClient route ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use multicast main thread is waiting for response.

use wireTap

http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html

route look like this

```
from("direct:commands")
.wireTap("direct:longRunningProces") //<<- seperate thread to process this route
    .to("direct:shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpClient");
```

here is a complete code
[github](https://github.com/RakeshBhat/rb-camelservlet218-xamples)

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: Adding to that, design perspective wiretap should be used to intercept the message between components for analyzing/debugging purpose. (ex: you can send a payload  to a different flow to log into database for audit purpose).  If you want to execute your long running process in separate thread - asynch way, just replace your direct with 'SEDA'

Comment: @GnanaGuru Do you mean like this ?

`from("direct:commands")
.multicast()
.to("seda:longRunningProces")
.to("direct:shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpClient");`

Comment: yup you can use as you mentioned. If you dont want to do mulicasting, you can use like this,  `from("direct:commands") .to("seda:longRunningProces") .to("direct:shortRunningProcessWhichMustSendRespondToHttpCli‌​ent");` note: multicast will cast same message to multiple endpoint; async in nature by default. In my example, seda alone behave as asynchronous way.

Comment: @GnanaGuru It doesn't work... The client is still waiting a response from the long running process

Comment: Ok. By default if your seda flow is trying to return something it will wait for response to come. So try to change your seda flow like `from("seda:longRunningProces?waitForTaskToComplete=Never")`.  Pl refer http://camel.apache.org/seda.html (waitForTaskToComplete option) ofor more information

Comment: @rak22 Very interesting. Thanks a lot ! According Gnana Guru, WireTap seems not to be the right pattern [link](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/WireTap.html). What is your opinion ?

Comment: @GnanaGuru It is working now as you describe with waitForTaskToComplete=Never" option. Thank you very much.

Comment: @T.Rex based on what camel doc says i suggested wireTap(http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html), and as we know a problem can be solved with different ways. WireTap worked for me, and async SEDA works as well. Now you have a choice :)

Comment: @rak22 & @T.Rex I agree, a problem can be solved in multiple ways. In the same time it will be always better to choose right fix. Just want to give two more link as ref for wiretap, 1.`camel.apache.org/eip.html` - wiretap grouped under system management section. 2. `dzone.com/articles/enterprise-integration` - verify the wiretap section. Hope it helps :-) Cheers!

Comment: if search SO, we can find similar question asked before and they used wireTap. in the below SO, "SEDA" route wrapped with wireTap.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691476/perform-wiretap-using-apache-camel
as per EIP its a pattern and gives a general overview of pattern for users to use. It doesn't restrict other use-cases. Contd..

Comment: And this SO here we are using Camel INT framework and as per Camel it does say, use WireTap "Wire Tap (from the EIP patterns) allows you to route messages to a separate location while they are being forwarded to the ultimate destination." There are no good or bad answers, whatever works for a given case.
found this link on SEDA, its a bit of concern.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2141851

Comment: i have coped link to code, the behavior using wireTap(direct:) and wireTap(seda:) is returning response body as JSON. However just using SEDA the auto binding to JSON doesn't happen. Just want to share this info. You can try yourself. Thank you, nice conversation.